# Practical ways to prevent Denial Of Service attacks

Tags: ip-spoofing, port-knocking

I am an undergraduate Computer Science student and was hoping to gain some knowledge of ways to help prevent Denial Of Service attacks.I read about some of here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking

But was having difficulty as to how to start to convert them to practical terms as simulation will require attacks too on the same system.Besides,these attacks become more deadlier if IP is spoofed. Any solutions for that and how can I simulate them.

Comment: How does port knocking or SYN cookies prevent IP Spoofing? Maybe the better question is: What do you think IP Spoofing is?

Comment: What do you mean by _how do I start translating that into programming terms_?

Comment: @Manuel Faux,translating into programming terms means how to go about implementing it

Comment: Moreover, what sort of attack do you think you need to protect against? Lying about an IP address is like sending somebody an envelope with a different return address on it; unless you can get into the destination mailbox (or are attempting to flood it with return mail), you have no idea if a response is even being sent.  For that matter, the mailman might not even deliver _your_ letter, if it thinks the return address is suspicious.  From the view of the party who receives your letter, there usually isn't a way to distinguish it from legitimate ones.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse,basically the DoS attacks,backed by IP Spoofing.

Comment: The fact that it's being sourced via IP Spoofing is irrelevant (you're still under a DoS attack), and you probably can't immediately distinguish it from a regular DoS attack (where no IP spoofing takes place).  Essentially, the attacker is mailing random people a return envelope for your company, which they then mail to you.  Both they (and you) initially believe the communication is genuine; you _have_ to deal with what you receive.  It's only after a couple of rounds that the system can figure it out.  And remember that you still receive legitimate requests during all this...

Comment: @user1369975 so, your question is really about DoS mitigation? You want to be able to block DoS attacks while allowing legitimate traffic?

Comment: @schroeder,well sort of.Well,actually when the person launching a DoS attack spoofs his IP,thats when it becomes even more threatening.So I wanted the ways to prevent IP spoofing.This will help to catch the culprits who launch DoS as well.

Comment: Then please update your question. You are mixing concepts and ideas and you need to be clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

IP spoofing is forging a new IP datagram impersonating a different machine from your own.  This is done by modifying the IP header, replacing the source address (your own) with a forged one.  This is successfull because IP is a stateless protocol and (in addition) provides no type of integrity on its own.

Any type of integrity control would prevent it such as TCP-AO or IPsec-AH.

TCP-AO (TCP authentication option) provides a MAC calculated over the TCP packet and some sections of the IP header (such as addresses).  A MAC algorithm provides message authentication, meaning this that we can detect if these fields have been modified in transit.

IPsec-AH calculates a MAC on the whole IP header and on the IP payload.  This MAC allows us to detect whether the whole IP datagram has been modified in transit.

SYN cookies have nothing to do with IP Spoofing.  SYN cookies are used to prevent DOS attacks.
Port knocking is really focused on avoiding your machine ports to be scanned.

Comment: Also egress filtering is a measure to prevent IP spoofing from your network with IPs from other networks. Maybe you want to add this to your answer.

Comment: Never heard of egress filtering. Does it have anything to do with ingress filtering?

Comment: Assuming I'm forging the IP headers, can't I forge the MAC calculations too?  Because I'd be the source of the packet, right?  Usually when you're protecting things from modification in-transit, there's a requirement of some shared secret between both parties (or knowledge of the results of the secret, for public/private keys).

Comment: MACs are calculated with a preshared key amongst two parties.  If you dont have the key, you cannot forge it.  These keys require secure distribution of course, but it was a bit out of scope of this question

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to defend against `IP spoofing` in the general case (i.e. if you need to be compatible with all existing infrastructure and protocols):

1) **Ingress filtering** - Block all packets entering your network from the Internet that have a source or destination address that is invalid (private address ranges, reserved ranges, or a source address that belongs to your network).

2) **Egress filtering** - Block all packets exiting your network to the Internet that have reserved or private source or destination addresses, plus any packets that have a source address other than one that belongs to your network.  This doesn't protect your network; rather, it acts to protect the rest of the Internet from IP spoofing attacks coming from your network.

Comment: These techniques will only work if the spoofed address is not sane. Granted, this is a great place to start. But, if I choose a legitimate IP to spoof, your filtering techniques will not work.

Comment: @schroeder, If you spoof a destination address that is valid, that's where the packet will (or at least, *should*) end up; spoofing a source address that sits somewhere else on the source network has limited value.

Comment: How do you 'spoof' a destination address? Spoofing my neighbor's address is of high value when I want to DoS an asset and not have it be traced to me in the logs. Reflection attacks are also a handy use of spoofing.

Comment: @schroeder, if you're in a position to send packets directly to the target's network, you can, for example, create a packet with a destination address in a private address range.  If you then send this packet to the target's router and they're using NAT, the router may pass the packet through into the private network, letting you access a computer that you normally couldn't.

Comment: That's not 'spoofing'. It is not meant to deceive or imitate or mask. If I'm at the border and send a packet to an internal destination, that's still a direct address, albeit one that takes advantage of poor border filtering. Again, filtering is important, but only protects against a small sub-set of IP spoofing scenarios.